# Iphone app with device UDID

Tags: iphone, ios, udid

I want to install my Iphone app to different iphones for testing. But every time I have do the provisioning profile thing.
How can I use the device UDID in my application while compilation so that they (apps) can be installed on those Iphones.....
Any idea?

Regards

Answer (score 7):

step :1 open your https://developer.apple.com/

step :2 open IOS dev Center

step :3 at the lest side menu bar click on "Devices".

step :4 then click on "Add New Device" fill your device UDID and Name. and then submit.

step :5 Now click on "App Id" in left menu bar. create your app id.

step :6 Now click on "Certificates" in left menu, choose the development field. now you should have a certificate with valid authority to upload it. for getting a certificate open "keychain access" then upper left corner of your desktop (near the apple icon) click on "Keychain Access", now choose ...certificate Assistant > Request a certificate from a certificate authority. then enter your mail in first row, choose saved to disk and then continue. now come to on upload this certificate to apple account.

step: 7 now click on "Provisioning" at left menu bar in apple site. choose the "development"  field then click on "New Profile" on right side. 
make your app profile, check the certificate, select an your app id, check the device. then submit.

step :8 now download your development certificate make sure the status should be "issued" and your provisioning profile name should be written there in "Provisioning Profile" fields. Download your provisioning profile also and make sure that the status is "Active".

step :9 double click on development certificate which you have downloaded and double click on your provisioning profile which you have downloaded.

step :10 now open your project and follow this.. Target > Info > Bundle Identifier. then rename your bundle identifier to what is your "app id".

step :11 Go to your Target > Build Setting > Code Signing > choose your signing identity. same code signing choose in your Projects > Build Setting > Code Signing.

step :12 now at upper left corner (near run button) set Scheme to "IOS Device". press window + B and then right click on "yourapp.app" show in finder then compress it with its provisioning profile and this zip file send to your client for testing.

for more detail see https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action.....

Thank You !!

Comment: if you build your app as Ad-Hoc, then it will only run if there's UDID is registered in the provisioning profile of your apple's account.
You can get your UDID by using iTunes or just by visiting this link "http://get.udid.io"; in safari browser of your iPhone/iPad and you will get your Device UDID, now you can use it for any purposes you need, like in apple's Provisioning Profile etc

Comment: where can i find "yourapp.app" ? I didn't find any file having extension .app

Comment: @NileshPol This is very old tutorial to making the build. Now you can simply archive the app and you would have an ipa file. For your query - You can find it in your project navigator -> Product -> yourAppName.app

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not allow this, app build as Ad-Hoc will only run if  and only if there is a UDID in the provisioning profile.

You will need to add the UDID for every iOS device you want to test you app via the provisionings portal.

There a solution to use a single Ad-Hoc profile for most of your apps: use a wildcard bundle ID (*) to make one provisioning profile word with more then one app. But you can't do this for apps that have APNS or iAP.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Apple guide for distributing your app for testing:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/35-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html

Hope it helps!

NOTE: You should have access to iOS Provisioning Portal in order to add your tester's device UDID.

Comment: if you build your app as Ad-Hoc, then it will only run if there's UDID is registered in the provisioning profile of your apple's account. You can get your UDID by using iTunes or just by visiting this link "get.udid.io";; in safari browser of your iPhone/iPad and you will get your Device UDID, now you can use it for any purposes you need, like in apple's Provisioning Profile etc